# Prevent ansible from parsing strings when passed through with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use `with_items` to specify a list of key/value pairs to be passed to a custom ansible module.

Problem arises when key or value string has list-like format. E.g., `"[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]"`. In such a case `with_items` presumably converts a string to a list and wrecks a havoc on my configuration.

Minimal example to reproduce (I'm using `debug` module, but with custom module the behavior is the same):

```yaml
- name: with_items_test
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ item.value }}"
  with_items:
    - { value: "[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]" }
```

> ```
> TASK [with_items_test] *********************************************************
> ok: [localhost] => (item={u'value': u"[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]"}) => {
>     "item": {
>         "value": "[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]"
>     }, 
>     "msg": [
>         [
>             "a", 
>             "b"
>         ], 
>         [
>             "c", 
>             "d"
>         ]
>     ]
> }
> ```

Without `with_items` such a string is passed just fine:

```yaml
- name: with_items_test
  debug: 
    msg: "[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]"
```

> ```
> TASK [with_items_test] *********************************************************
> ok: [localhost] => {
>     "msg": "[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not about how `with_items` work, but about Ansible template engine.
Use `string` filter to prevent conversion. See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41147661/2795592) answer for details.

```yaml
- name: with_items_test
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ item.value | string }}"
  with_items:
    - { value: "[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]" }
```