# How to use variable inside json string in Ansible uri module?

Tags: ansible

Using ansible 2.5.3 on ubuntu 16.10.

I need to include a variable in a JSON string for the body tag of the Ansible uri module. I have tried various things. My latest try looks like this in the below task in a role:

```
- name: REST POST Example
  uri:
    url: "{{ webapp_url }}/api/orgs"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body: "{ \"name\": \"{{ project_name }}\" }"
    validate_certs: no
    user: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
```

In my playbook I define the `project_name` variable:

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
      project_name: "SAMPLE_PROJECT"
```

But when I run the playbook the `project_name` variable does not seem to get expanded correctly:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: unhashable type
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: unhashable type", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "https://webapp/api/orgs"}

In the above role/task. If I hardcode the body like:

```
body: "{\"name\": \"SAMPLE_PROJECT\"}"
```

it works fine. But I cannot do that I need the variable in there. Any suggestions on how to fix:

```
body: "{ \"name\": \"{{ project_name }}\" }"
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `json` as the body type inside `body_format` parameter:

```
- name: REST POST Example
  uri:
    url: "{{ webapp_url }}/api/orgs"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body: "{ \"name\": \"{{ project_name }}\" }"
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
    user: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
```

---

When you use `body: "{\"name\": \"SAMPLE_PROJECT\"}"`, the value is represented internally as a string (`AnsibleUnicode`).

When you use `body: "{ \"name\": \"{{ project_name }}\" }"`, the value becomes a dictionary (`dict`), because it goes through the templating engine, after which the output is mapped into a Python object (it doesn't happen with plain strings).

<sup>Trivia: you can still trick Ansible to think it is a string by adding a space before first `{`. See [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41144922/2947502).</sup>

`uri` module uses `body_format: raw` by default and it expects a string, if it finds an object it fails; refer to [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13308).

Comment: Thank you for this answer - this was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 6):

Ansible ca interpret YAML as json automatically, I recommand the method below :

```
- name: REST POST Example
  uri:
    url: "{{ webapp_url }}/api/orgs"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body:
      name: "{{ projectname }}"
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
    user: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
```