# ansible passing JSON as a string without quoting it

Tags: json, ansible

I was running into this particularly painful Ansible task of:

1. Reading JSON from a file.
2. Passing the JSON as a string to helm, BUT not quoting it.

```
- name: deploy release
  community.kubernetes.helm:
    name: my_release
    chart_ref: ./charts/my_chart
    release_namespace: "{{namespace}}"
    state: "{{state}}"
    release_values:
          x: "{{ lookup('file', './stuff.json') }}"
```

What I want the helm values file to look like is:

```
x: |
  { "hello": "world" }
```

The issue I ran into with the following lookup `{{ lookup('file', './stuff.json') }}` is that ansible will interpret it as a dict and pass the dict to helm. This does not work as I need a string. Here's what the output in the helm values file looks like:

```
x:
  hello: world
```

Then I tried `{{ lookup('file', './stuff.json') | quote}}`. Ansible passes a string to helm, but that string has a quote around it. When I try to read the JSON in my deployment, I get a parse error. Here's what the output would look like:

```
x: '{ "hello": "world" }'
```

I even tried `{{ lookup('file', './stuff.json') | to_json }}`, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144922/ansible-passing-json-string-in-environment-to-shell-module), but that failed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{{ lookup('file', './stuff.json') | string }}` will force Ansible to evaluate it as a string without adding quotes.

There are several examples in [*Using filters to manipulate data*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) that use this filter.

Documentation for the filter can be found in the [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#string) documentation. The documentation states that the filter will:

> Make a string unicode if it isn’t already. That way a markup string is not converted back to unicode.

I'm not particularly sure *why* this corrects the issue, but it did.